# why is firebase firestore rule denies write, indicating '...==...' and '&&' as false

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-console

Firestore security rules denying access.

Rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{id} {
      allow create, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == id;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

playground rules indicate `'...==...'` and '&&' as false. What is wrong with this? Help appreciated very much!

Full rules and screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it just says 'false'. when i run my app it says 'insufficient or missing permission'

Comment: We can't see the UID of the user you're testing with in the screenshot, but I'm assuming your is something different than `user`, which is the document you're trying to write. Since your rules require `request.auth.uid == id`, the UID must match the ID of the document you're writing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allow create, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == id;
```

From your screenshot, you are running an update simulation.

1. `request.auth != null` will fail if user is not logged in.
2. `request.auth.uid == id` will fail if uid != id;

From your screenshot, we can see that authenticated is set to true. Therefore condition 1 will pass.
It is presently failing because of the 2nd condition. `request.auth.uid == id`

Presently, the id == 'user', but request.auth.uid != 'user';

Solution. Set your request.auth.uid to 'user'. To do that, go under authenticated, under firebase UID, put 'user' (as your firebase uid). It should work.

NB: it is possible that you are not struturing your data properly. Your present data structure is something like 'users/user', instead it should be 'users/{userId}' where userId is generated by firebase when user creates account.

Comment: thanks, but am confused. how do I set request.auth.uid to 'user', do you mean request.auth.uid == 'user'? also, under firebase uid, put 'user' - u mean, in the left column? very new to firestore... thanks again!

Comment: you set request.auth.uid to 'user', by going to the left column, under firebase uid, put 'user'. Yes. You're always welcome.

Comment: got it! thanks! I did not notice the Firebase UID on the left before. Thanks!